# What's wrong? I can't figure out the problem because I don't need "$"

Tags: missing

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.257 ![](Peter01_
                  files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-7-1.pdf)<!-- --> 


ggplot(data_peter02) +
  aes(x = region) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#440154") +
  labs(
    x = "Régions",
    y = "Nombre de répondants",
    title = "Réparition des répondants par région en Belgique"
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Your question is impossible to understand. For a start, please provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE) that triggers the error.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you're using some tool that generates LaTeX code, and such tool is buggy when the path contain the `_` character.

Answer (score 3):

Please always provide a minimal working example (MWE) and a meaningful title without greetings or anything. It should be a short and precise description of your problem.

About your problem:
Underscores are not allowed in normal LaTeX text. Replace `_` with `\_` and that's it.